# Save Outlook Attachment to Folder on PC using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to save attachments from a sub-folder in Outlook to a folder on my C drive using Excel VBA.

For example, in my inbox folder I have a sub-folder called 'data' and in this folder there are emails with different excel attachments of different data but with the same formatting and the same attachment name but with an updated date (Eg: "Attachment name + 28 March").

These emails are sent daily. I want all attachments, not already saved, saved to a folder on my C drive and then open each attachment to extract the relevant data to Excel.

I am able to extract the relevant data once the files are in my C drive but I am unable to set up a path from my Excel to Outlook without Outlook VBA (which I don't want to do).

This is what I have so far: (the comments are for my benefit because I am new to this)

```
Sub attachmentsave()

Dim olook As Outlook.Application
Dim omailitem As Outlook.mailitem
'whenever dealing with folders we need to define outlook.namespace This is a class that opens the gate for me to access all outlook folders
Dim onamespace As Outlook.Namespace

Dim fol As Outlook.Folder 'we need to tell vba where we have out emails with attachments stored
Dim atmt As Outlook.Attachment '.attachment is a class that will help us deal with emails that have attachments

Set olook = New Outlook.Application
Set omailitem = olook.CreateItem(olmailitem)

'messaging application protocol interface
Set onamespace = olook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
Set fol = onamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

For Each omailitem In fol.items
    For Each atmt In omailitem.attachments

        atmt.SaveAsFile "C:/" & atmt.FileName
        'all attachments in inbox should be save in C drive

    Next

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You are asking for too much help in one go for this site.  You need to break your requirement into little steps and research those steps one by one.  It is easier to write and run Outlook VBA under Outlook but you can run Outlook VBA from Excel if you really must.  I will show you the first step which is to open an instance of Outlook from Excel and run code under that instance to find the correct folder.  But first: why not write your code using the Outlook VBA Editor?

Comment: @TonyDallimore long story but I need this to work on multiple PCs and some do not want their outlook modified. Hence exce vba is best for this scenario

Comment: OK: that is a sensible reason; it is difficult to move Outlook code from one Outlook installation to another.  I should have some time this afternoon to create something.

Comment: @TonyDallimore sounds great!

Comment: I do not know if you get a message telling you an answer has been updated. I know you are told if a comment is posted against your question so this ensures you know to check my improved answer.

Comment: Why are you saving in the root (C;\) folder?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko can be any folder really, just chose that out of random. Why do you ask?

Comment: Because unless you turn UAC off in Windows, that line will raise an exception even if you are a local admin.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko erm... what does that mean..?

Comment: It means a regular user has no write access to the root of the C;\ drive.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko it doesn’t have to be the c drive. Really I just want it to save to a folder in my documents

Comment: I was just pointing to a problem in your *existing* code. I not sure what you mean by "unable to set up a path".

Comment: So the basic issue is: there are emails in a sub folder of my outlook and within each email is an attachment that comes with the same title apart from a date change on each one. I need an excel macro to go into that sub folder of my outlook and save the attachments of each email in a folder on my computer. Once that is done I will run another macro to open each excel file and pull the relevant data that I need into an excel workbook

Answer (score 0):

You need a macro-enabled Excel workbook with a reference to "Microsoft Output nn.n Object Library" where “nn.n” depends on the version of Office you are running.  Please do not mix versions; I have never tried but I understand it causes problems.

I am assuming you are familiar with Excel VBA and know how to create a macro-enabled workbook. From your comments, I assume you do not know about references.

Much of the power of VBA is not native but comes from libraries which you can reference if you need their functionality. Open the VBA Editor and click Tools and then References. You will get a long list of available references.  Those at the top will be ticked.  For example, "Microsoft Excel nn.n Object Library" will be ticked.  Without this reference, the compiler would not know what a range or a worksheet was.  Note: "nn.n" depends on the version of Office you are using.  For me, the value is "16.0" because I am using Office 365.

Unticked references are in alphabetic sequence.  Scroll down the list until you find "Microsoft Outlook nn.n Object Library".  Click the box to the left to tick this reference.  Click "OK". If you click Tools then References again you will see "Microsoft Outlook nn.n Object Library" ticked and near the top. The compiler now has access to the definitions of MailItem, Folder and the rest of the Outlook Object Model.

Copy the code below to a new module:

```
Option Explicit
Sub ListStores()

  ' Needs reference to "Microsoft Output nn.n Object Library"
  ' where "nn.n" depends on the version of Outlook you are using.

  Dim AppOut As New Outlook.Application
  Dim InxStoreCrnt As Long
  Dim FldrInbox As Outlook.Folder

  With AppOut
    With .Session
      Debug.Print "List of stores:"
      For InxStoreCrnt = 1 To .Folders.Count
        Debug.Print "  " & .Folders(InxStoreCrnt).Name
      Next

      Set FldrInbox = .GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
      Debug.Print "Store for default Inbox: " & FldrInbox.Parent.Name

    End With
  End With

  AppOut.Quit
  Set AppOut = Nothing

End Sub
```

VBA usually has more than one method of achieving a desired effect.  You have used “NameSpace” in your code whilst I have used “Session”.  The documentation says these two methods are equivalent.  If you write your own code, you can pick whichever method you prefer.  But if you go looking for useful snippets, you must be ready for other people having different preferences.

`Dim AppOut As New Outlook.Application` creates an instance of Outlook that will access Outlook’s files on behalf of the macro.

```
With AppOut
  With .Session
     :   :   :   :
  End With
End With
```

I can replace `:   :   :   :` with any Outlook VBA.  If an Excel macro tries to access an email, the user will be warned and asked to give permission for the macro to run.

Outlook keeps emails, appointments, tasks and so on in files it calls Stores.  You may see these called PST files because most have an extension of PST but an OST file is also a store.  You may see them called Accounts because, by default, Outlook creates one store per email account.  However, you can create as many extra stores as you want, none of which will be Accounts.

This code will create a list of the stores you can access:

```
  Debug.Print "List of stores:"
  For InxStoreCrnt = 1 To .Folders.Count
    Debug.Print "  " & .Folders(InxStoreCrnt).Name
  Next
```

The output might look something like:

```
List of stores:
  Outlook Data File
  Smith John@ISPOne.com
  Archive Folders
  Backup
  John Smith@ISPTwo.com
  OutlookOutlook
```

The above is based on my home installation.  A work installation is likely to be somewhat different.  The differences will depend on the options chosen during installation.  A work installation is also likely to included shared folders which I do not have on my system.

If you look at your folder pane, you will have names with other names indented underneath.  The names be will the stores and will match the stores listed by the macro although the sequence will probably be different.  The other names in the folder pane will be the folders within each store.

The last bit of my macro is:

```
  Set FldrInbox = .GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
  Debug.Print "Store for default Inbox: " & FldrInbox.Parent.Name
```

You have similar code to access an Inbox but this may not be the Inbox you want.  On my system, this code outputs:

```
Store for default Inbox: Outlook Data File
```

“Outlook Data File” is Outlook’s default store.  On my system, the calendar and my tasks are held in this store but my emails are not.  I have two email accounts and each has their own store.

Try this above macro.  Does `GetDefaultFolder`find the Inbox you need to access?

Now add this macro:

```
Sub ListStoresAndFirstEmails()

  ' Needs reference to "Microsoft Output nn.n Object Library"
  ' where "nn.n" depends on the version of Outlook you are using.

  Dim AppOut As New Outlook.Application
  Dim InxFldrCrnt As Long
  Dim InxStoreCrnt As Long
  Dim FldrInbox As Outlook.Folder

  With AppOut
    With .Session
      Debug.Print "List of stores and first emails:"
      For InxStoreCrnt = 1 To .Folders.Count
        Debug.Print "  " & .Folders(InxStoreCrnt).Name
        For InxFldrCrnt = 1 To .Folders(InxStoreCrnt).Folders.Count
          If .Folders(InxStoreCrnt).Folders(InxFldrCrnt).Name = "Inbox" Then
            Set FldrInbox = .Folders(InxStoreCrnt).Folders(InxFldrCrnt)
            If FldrInbox.Items.Count > 0 Then
              With FldrInbox.Items(1)
                Debug.Print "    Subject: " & .Subject
                Debug.Print "    Received: " & .ReceivedTime
                Debug.Print "    From: " & .SenderEmailAddress
              End With
            End If
            Exit For
          End If
        Next
      Next
    End With
  End With

  AppOut.Quit
  Set AppOut = Nothing
End Sub
```

This macro is also about investigating your stores.  The macro scans down your stores.  For each store, it scans down the list of level 1 folders looking for "Inbox".  If it finds "Inbox", it assumes the oldest item in it is a MailItem and outputs its subject, received time and sender.  If the oldest item is not a MailItem, you will get an error. I almost hope you do get an error to demonstrate the importance of not making assumptions.

Finally add:

```
Sub ListAttachments()

  Dim AppOut As New Outlook.Application
  Dim InxAttachCrnt As Long
  Dim InxItemCrnt As Long
  Dim InxStoreCrnt As Long
  Dim FldrData As Outlook.Folder

  With AppOut
    With .Session
      Set FldrData = .Folders("Outlook Data File").Folders("Inbox").Folders("Data")
    End With
  End With

  Debug.Print "List emails with attachments within: ";
  Debug.Print " " & FldrData.Name & " of " & FldrData.Parent.Name & _
              " of " & FldrData.Parent.Parent.Name
  With FldrData
    For InxItemCrnt = 1 To FldrData.Items.Count
      If .Items(InxItemCrnt).Class = olMail Then
        With .Items(InxItemCrnt)
          If .Attachments.Count > 0 Then
            Debug.Print "    Subject: " & .Subject
            Debug.Print "    Received: " & .ReceivedTime
            Debug.Print "    From: " & .SenderEmailAddress
            For InxAttachCrnt = 1 To .Attachments.Count
              Debug.Print "      " & InxAttachCrnt & " " & .Attachments(InxAttachCrnt).DisplayName
            Next
          End If
        End With
      End If
    Next
  End With

  AppOut.Quit
  Set AppOut = Nothing

End Sub
```

I always keep some junk emails in store "Outlook Data File" for testing purposes.

In `Set FldrData = .Folders("Outlook Data File").Folders("Inbox").Folders("Data")` you need to replace "Outlook Data File" with the name of the store containing the emails of interest. If I understand correctly, the emails are in folder "Data" under folder "Inbox".  If I have misunderstood, notice how I have used a chain of "Folders(xxxx)" to reach the required folder.  In earlier emails I have used indices to reach stores and folders. Here I have specified a specific folder.

Within that folder I look for MailItems (showing how to avoid other items) and if they have attachments, list some properties of the email and the names of its attachments.

This is as far as I can go because I do not fully understand your explanation of how attachments are named or where you want attachments saved.

Comment: Hi, thanks for all the help. It breaks on the first line:

Comment: Dim AppOut As New Outlook.Application [User-defined type not defined]

Comment: The code needs a reference to the Outlook Object model.  Did you set this reference?

Comment: Did you understand the first paragraph of my answer?

Comment: I will have to digest it tomorrow and get back to you if thats okay.

Comment: I will add an explanation of references ready for you to look at tomorrow. It is 21:27 here in England.  I will be online tomorrow about 9:30 UK time.

Comment: hi, it breaks at sub() ListAttachments()... set fldrdata = .folders(“Outlook Data File”).folders(“inbox”).folders(“data”)

Comment: Have you replaced "Outlook Data File" with the name of the store containing the "Inbox" of interest?  Is there a folder "Data" under that "Inbox"?  What error message do you get?.

Comment: the subfolder in my outlook is called “data” and the folder “data” is in is just my inbox

Comment: In your folder pane you will have "xxxxxx" and under that the names of several folders of which one will be "Inbox".  Under "Inbox" you will have "data"  What is the value of "xxxxxx"?  Do you get the error while the routine is compiling or while it is running?  What is the error you get?

Comment: Fyi I was able to solve the problem. Found a much simpler method. Will share soon